# How to collect all the liked user names of an Instagram picture using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
while len(user_names) < int(no_of_likes):
    popup = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div")
    self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", popup)
    time.sleep(1)
    sflw = BeautifulSoup(popup.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser')
    for each in sflw.find_all('a'):
      if 'title' in each.attrs.keys():
          if each.attrs['title'] not in user_names:
                  user_names.append(each.attrs['title'])
    print(len(user_names))
    print(user_names)
```

I tried this, it's scrolling to the end but missing few usernames so it's iterating infinitely.

Comment: So I see you have gotten your scrolling part working fine. I would suggest this. Scroll to the bottom, when you reach the bottom, break the loop. Then use findAll to get all the users visible, and append them to your list.

Comment: Here what I did is  when total no of usernames is greater than likes it breaks. How do I break loop after reaching the end. I mean how will I know I reached the end without collecting the usernames

Comment: Each username in the like list should be of some form of a li or div tag. Find out the reference for that and use findAll to find the number of those users. Then compare it against the number of likes on the post. (I am not sure if the picture poster themselves counts as a like so you will need to check that). You can probably also check if the "load more" button goes away.